# Align 3 tables vertically when one of them is longer than others

Tags: tables, alignment

Hei,I have three tables which I put beside each other. one of the tables is longer and they don't get aligned. Is there a way to make them start on the same level. I wonder also if it is possible to move the left table little bit more to the left.

````
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} % 'twoside' when printing
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow, makecell}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
% Center the table horizontally
\newcolumntype{P}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
% Center the table vertically
\newcolumntype{M}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
% Center the table horizontally and vertically
\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Global Sensitivity Analysis}
 \section{Sensitivity analysis of the Non-dimensional model}
 \subsection{Sobol method}
 \subsubsection{ $x$}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{T}$ &  ${S_{T}}_{conf}$ \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.994552 &          0.124695 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.828068 &          0.107525 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.803421 &          0.104188 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.692074 &          0.096774 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.546865 &          0.083055 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.509429 &          0.817009 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.420421 &          0.068414 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.128809 &          0.038012 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.085175 &          0.030469 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.013422 &          0.011932 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.006910 &          0.008447 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{1}$ &  ${S_{1}}_{conf}$ \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.072319 &          0.028199 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.000922 &          0.007176 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000189 &          0.000836 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000126 &          0.001144 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000105 &          0.000504 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000113 &          0.000405 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000125 &          0.000836 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000218 &          0.000481 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    & -0.002986 &          0.004480 \\
            $x_{0}$        & -0.003422 &          0.004040 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  & -0.003677 &          0.006299 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{2}$ &  ${S_{2}}_{conf}$ \\
            \midrule
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\beta_{2}$)       &  0.045929 &          0.038401 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $g_{12}$)          &  0.045331 &          0.050504 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\omega_{22}$)     &  0.037668 &          0.044571 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $x_{0}$)           &  0.036517 &          0.067326 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)     &  0.026426 &          0.047685 \\
            ($g_{12}$, $\omega_{22}$)        &  0.022492 &          0.023857 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $x_{0}$)           &  0.012171 &          0.015839 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, ${y_{1}}_{0}$)     &  0.011692 &          0.014563 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\epsilon_{2}$)    &  0.010702 &          0.014339 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\omega_{11}$)     &  0.010701 &          0.014433 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\epsilon_{1}$)    &  0.010631 &          0.014380 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\gamma_{12}$)     &  0.010598 &          0.014386 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)     &  0.010195 &          0.014696 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $g_{12}$)          &  0.008001 &          0.015855 \\
            ($\omega_{22}$, ${y_{1}}_{0}$)   &  0.007718 &          0.009530 \\
            ($\omega_{22}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)   &  0.007267 &          0.009674 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\omega_{11}$)     &  0.007134 &          0.041062 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\omega_{22}$)     &  0.005735 &          0.006284 \\
            ($\omega_{22}$, $x_{0}$)         &  0.005324 &          0.006108 \\
            ($g_{12}$, $x_{0}$)              &  0.004350 &          0.012807 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\gamma_{12}$)     &  0.004098 &          0.039525 \\
            ($g_{12}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)        &  0.002973 &          0.011435 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\epsilon_{1}$)    &  0.002349 &          0.039998 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\epsilon_{2}$)    &  0.001779 &          0.039945 \\
            ($\epsilon_{2}$, $\omega_{22}$)  &  0.001720 &          0.003419 \\
            ($x_{0}$, ${y_{1}}_{0}$)         &  0.001067 &          0.001968 \\
            ($\epsilon_{2}$, $g_{12}$)       &  0.001035 &          0.001910 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sensitivity of Mean value of $x$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `[t]` alignment for each of the three tabular environments

```
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lrr}
```

This will align all three top-rules at the baseline of the enclosing line.
(I don't understand the point of `\toprule` when it doesn't take care of that that problem.) Since only the three tabulars are on that line, it won't be a problem for this document. You could put `\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}` or some such length at the beginning if you find too much white space there.

js bibra is right that the tables are too long for the page using the layout parameters and font sizes given.

I don't see what the subtable environments are good for, but I'll assume they are useful for the "real" document.

Comment: is this `\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}` to move the left table to the left ,in that case where I should place it ,is it after `\begin{table}`. I used subtable environments to get title for each individual table and a global title for the three tables.

Comment: That's `\vspace`, not `\hspace`, so it is to move all three tables upwards, if desired. It would go after `\begin{table}[H]`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the footnotesize but it will not fit the table on same page

Table column separator can be aadjusted to choice

Midrule thickness can be adjusted
[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} % 'twoside' when printing
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow, makecell}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
% Center the table horizontally
\newcolumntype{P}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
% Center the table vertically
\newcolumntype{M}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
% Center the table horizontally and vertically
\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Global Sensitivity Analysis}
 \section{Sensitivity analysis of the Non-dimensional model}
 \subsection{Sobol method}
 \subsubsection{ $x$}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering

        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{T}$ &  ${S_{T}}_{conf}$ \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.994552 &          0.124695 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.828068 &          0.107525 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.803421 &          0.104188 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.692074 &          0.096774 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.546865 &          0.083055 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.509429 &          0.817009 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.420421 &          0.068414 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.128809 &          0.038012 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.085175 &          0.030469 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.013422 &          0.011932 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.006910 &          0.008447 \\ \midrule[2pt]
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\


        \end{tabular}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{1}$ &  ${S_{1}}_{conf}$ \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.072319 &          0.028199 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.000922 &          0.007176 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000189 &          0.000836 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000126 &          0.001144 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000105 &          0.000504 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000113 &          0.000405 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000125 &          0.000836 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000218 &          0.000481 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    & -0.002986 &          0.004480 \\
            $x_{0}$        & -0.003422 &          0.004040 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  & -0.003677 &          0.006299 \\ \midrule[2pt]
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\
            &&\\


        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{2}$ &  ${S_{2}}_{conf}$ \\
            \midrule
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\beta_{2}$)       &  0.045929 &          0.038401 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $g_{12}$)          &  0.045331 &          0.050504 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\omega_{22}$)     &  0.037668 &          0.044571 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $x_{0}$)           &  0.036517 &          0.067326 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)     &  0.026426 &          0.047685 \\
            ($g_{12}$, $\omega_{22}$)        &  0.022492 &          0.023857 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $x_{0}$)           &  0.012171 &          0.015839 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, ${y_{1}}_{0}$)     &  0.011692 &          0.014563 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\epsilon_{2}$)    &  0.010702 &          0.014339 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\omega_{11}$)     &  0.010701 &          0.014433 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\epsilon_{1}$)    &  0.010631 &          0.014380 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\gamma_{12}$)     &  0.010598 &          0.014386 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)     &  0.010195 &          0.014696 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $g_{12}$)          &  0.008001 &          0.015855 \\
            ($\omega_{22}$, ${y_{1}}_{0}$)   &  0.007718 &          0.009530 \\
            ($\omega_{22}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)   &  0.007267 &          0.009674 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\omega_{11}$)     &  0.007134 &          0.041062 \\
            ($\beta_{1}$, $\omega_{22}$)     &  0.005735 &          0.006284 \\
            ($\omega_{22}$, $x_{0}$)         &  0.005324 &          0.006108 \\
            ($g_{12}$, $x_{0}$)              &  0.004350 &          0.012807 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\gamma_{12}$)     &  0.004098 &          0.039525 \\
            ($g_{12}$, ${y_{2}}_{0}$)        &  0.002973 &          0.011435 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\epsilon_{1}$)    &  0.002349 &          0.039998 \\
            ($\beta_{2}$, $\epsilon_{2}$)    &  0.001779 &          0.039945 \\
            ($\epsilon_{2}$, $\omega_{22}$)  &  0.001720 &          0.003419 \\
            ($x_{0}$, ${y_{1}}_{0}$)         &  0.001067 &          0.001968 \\
            ($\epsilon_{2}$, $g_{12}$)       &  0.001035 &          0.001910 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
     \end{minipage} 
    \caption{Sensitivity of Mean value of $x$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thats one way to go -- thanks -- would you like to edit the answer

Comment: (Replaced comment because it sounded too petty/nasty.) I think that tabular `[t]` alignment is a better choice than filling tables with empty lines.

Comment: a demo would be nice as an education please edit the code above